# Upload picture to facebook from unity

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-sdk-3.0, facebook-unity-sdk

Im working on a unity game where you can take a picture and upload this picture to facebook from unity along with some tags and stuff (much like friendsmash). The problem is that i do not have a web-server that i can put the screenshots on, and the Fb.Feeb(picture:) attribute only accepts urls.

I have read that you can use HTTP POST to post the picture to the users images and then use that link in picture:, but i dont know anything about HTTP POST and i couldnt figure out how to do it.

I have also read that you can use FB.API() to somehow do this, but i couldnt figure it out.

Any sample code would be greatly appreciated.

My current code:

```
private string _path = "file://" + System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Images/image.png");

void Start ()
    {
        if (!FB.IsLoggedIn)
            FB.Login("email, publish_actions, publish_stream, user_photos", LoginCallback);
        StartCamera();
    }


private void OnBragClicked()

{
    FbDebug.Log("OnBragClicked");

//Post(); <-- dont know how

FB.Feed(
    linkCaption: "#hashtag",
    picture: "???",
    linkName: "Im hashtaging!",
    link: "https://apps.facebook.com/" + FB.AppId + "/?challenge_brag=" + (FB.IsLoggedIn ?  FB.UserId : "guest")
    );
}


 void TakeSnapshot()

{
    _snap = new Texture2D(_webCamTexture.width, _webCamTexture.height);
    _snap.SetPixels(_webCamTexture.GetPixels());
    _snap.Apply();

//System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(_path, _snap.EncodeToPNG());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The facebook sdk does have a way to make this happen after all. You need to use Fb.API().
This is the way it worked for me:

```
private void TakeScreenshot()
{
    var snap = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    snap.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);
    snap.Apply();
    var screenshot = snap.EncodeToPNG();

    var wwwForm = new WWWForm();
    wwwForm.AddBinaryData("image", screenshot, "barcrawling.png");

    FB.API("me/photos", HttpMethod.POST, LogCallback, wwwForm);
}
```

In general terms, to add some sort of caption, it's along the lines...

```
private byte[] postcardAsBytes;
string textMessage = "Play this great game at http://blah.com.";
Dictionary<string, object> d = new Dictionary<string, object>
  {
  { "message", textMessage },
  { "picture", postcardAsBytes }
  };
Facebook.instance.graphRequest(
        "me/photos", HTTPVerb.POST, d, yourCompletionHandler);
// in this example using the prime31 plugin, rather than the fb sdk
```

The key field seems to be "message". Confusingly, the "dictionary" field documented by FB, seems to just not work, so try "message" at first.

Comment: Is there any way to add caption/predefined text or description with it?

Comment: Not that i have found, sorry

Comment: @Imran sure you can: wwwForm.AddField("message","Your message here"); wwwForm.AddField("description","Your description here");

Comment: hi @UserQuestion - thanks for this, but the problem is, ***will this work after Aug 8*** 2016??  Does anyone know?  Thanks.  I asked about it here ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38232224/facebook-post-to-wall-using-me-photos-in-2-1-facebook