# Share image to Facebook from iOS/Android using Facebook API in Unity3D

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I am using Facebook SDK plugin for social sharing in my app.

I am able to logged in and sharing photos on user wall.

I want to upload that image on the Facebook which I have created from facebook account. Is there is Facebook API for sharing image on the facebook page.

Please help, for example my facebook page Url is https://www.facebook.com/demoneptune/ Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload picture to facebook from unity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215946/upload-picture-to-facebook-from-unity)

Answer (score 1):

You need some permissions from facebook, most important permission is "publish_actions".

You need page_ID of that facebook page to which you want to post.

Then try this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[params setObject:@"Your own message" forKey:@"message"];
[params setObject:@"facebook_page_id_path_string" forKey:@"place"];

[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"result %@",result);
NSLog(@"error %@",error);
if (!error) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Posted!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
     double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
     dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
     dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
     });
  } else {
      NSString *message = @"There was a problem sharing. Please try again!";
      [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
  }
}];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks ... what is the **"place"** key??  (BTW this is for Unity3D, not objC  :)  But the code is basically the same, thanks.)

Comment: its usually said to use **"me/photos"**.  What is the difference with **"me/feed'**?  Thanks...

Comment: I've came through the same requirement and worked on many ways(publish_stream, me/feed, ...). There is a demo graph API in developers.facebook.com. There i came to know about "me/feed". It worked and I've followed it @Joe Blow.

Comment: good one @satishA, with me/feed **does it end up on the user's "wall" ?**  Thanks.

Comment: with me/feed and page_id, it is posted to that page. But according to facebook, if user's post to any other users wall/pages, it also end up on his/her wall too @Joe Blow.